# NameError in HomeController#action While Using CanCanCan Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I am new to rails. I am using CanCanCan (v1.10) and rails (v4.2).
While I am putting "authorize_resource" inside ApplicationController, I can not access my home pages.

Sample code in applcation controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  authorize_resource
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:danger] = t :cancancan_access_denied_text
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

It show me the following error:

```
NameError in StaticPagesController#home
```

Comment: Please add `StaticPagesController` code to the question and full error message (there should be a string number specified).

Comment: app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end

Comment: Error message in browser:

NameError in StaticPagesController#home 

uninitialized constant StaticPage

    def resource_class_with_parent
      parent_resource ? {parent_resource => resource_class} : resource_class
    end

    def resource_instance=(instance)

Comment: It's better to edit the question itself and add information to it, as comments are only for short messages and not for code snippets. Be careful about people who you ask help from and try to format questions in the most readable way.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `authorize_resource` because it tries to guess model name from the controller name, but you don't have `StaticPage` model in your app. Instead, you should call `authorize!` in the beginning of each action, like so:

```
def home
  authorize!
  ...
end
```

So you need to remove `authorize_resource` from `ApplicationController` and use it only in those controllers that have associated model. Controllers without model should have `authorize!` in actions instead.

Comment: My PM's requirement is to use authorized_resource in ApplicationController. So I need to find out a work-around to it.

I was trying to use "authorize_resource class: false" in StaticPagesController but it did not work in my case.

Comment: Actually, this is a bad practice. `authorize_resource` shouldn't be used in `ApplicationController` as it produces the problems you have. You should convince your PM not to do so. Here's the creator of CanCan explains this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/138#issuecomment-381834

Also try to add `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` to the beginning of `StaticPagesController` and continue to use `authorize!` in each action. But I'm not sure it'll work.

Comment: Right, your approach works fine. But here another problem raises. I also used "Devise" to authenticate. So authorize_resource in ApplicationController also make Devise controllers (session or registration) access denied.

Comment: You can generate Devise controllers: `rails generate devise:controllers`, edit them and add `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` to them.